# predicate logic of a domain of discourse

Tags: discrete-mathematics, predicate-logic

If Px = "x is possile" Mx = "x is a mission"

**STATEMENT:** m is not a possible mission.

I would assume 2 ways

1. For all of x. (Not Px and not Mx)
2. For all of x. (Not Px) and Mx (because it can be a mission but not possible)

Is this right? Thanks.

Comment: This is extremely unclear. What is the question? Note that *"$m$ is not a possible mission"* is a statement, not a question. What are you asked to do here?

Comment: If 1 or 2 is correct for the statement? If I am doing this correct.

Comment: Your 2. is correct, if you mean "not (Px and Mx)".

Answer (score 1):

$(Mm \wedge \neg Pm) \vee \neg Mm$
Equivalently
$Mm \rightarrow \neg Pm$